# How is programming different when you do CPU bound tasks vs I/O tasks

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

I am learning **mutithreading and asynchronous programming in C#.**

I understand the concepts of **CPU bound** and **I/O bound**, so I realize when I am in one scenario and when in the other.

The point is I don't **How is programming different in one scenario and in the other**; in the context of TPL, Tasks, Multithreading, Async, etc.

Maybe seeing one example of both of them will be helpful.

Comment: There is virtually no real difference between CPU / I/O bound programming. Multithreading is a huge topic for it alone that even small examples won't be suffice. It looks like your question are actually many different questions.

Comment: CPU bound and I/O bound have different bottlenecks. Use async on I/O bound to avoid wasting cpu cycles while waiting on the I/O. Use multiple threads on CPU bound tasks to take advantage of more than one core. Tasks/TPL are just part of .NET Async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no special programming for i/o or cpu bound, 
Almost every program you develop has some i/o actions and on runtime they will be in i/o state , a program that is mainly i/o operations called i/o bound.

Its all about your specific program, 
when you need input or output to your program you need to get it in some way,
untill it is being recieved, the program needs to wait for it, but there is no need for a special type of programing for that.